# The simplest way to sum the elements of a n*1 -matrix

Tags: summation

Suppose we have  a 10*1 (n*m)  matrix:

```
b = {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}} // MatrixForm
```

Now, if I want to sum the elements of this matrix from n=1 to n=10, what is the simplest way to do that. This simple way is required specially for large n.

Comment: `Total[b, {1,2}]`

Comment: `m = ... // MatrixForm` <- Do not do this.  It will make your matrix unusable for computation if you wrap the data into MatrixForm.  MatrixForm is only for display.

Comment: BTW I did give you the reference to Total [just yesterday](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157925/labeling-elements-of-a-matrix#comment421013_157925).  I also showed that searching for "mathematica sum elements of matrix" with google returns `Total` as the first hit.  Please do search before asking.

Comment: Thank you  Szabolcs for your useful comment!

Comment: But if I want to sum these elements using summation over n ?? This is my questions.

Comment: Because the matrix I deal with has a large size, summation over n will simplify my calculation. More over there are terms in my equations given in terms of n .

Comment: Use parentheses to isolate the definition from the display wrapper: `(m = ...)//MatrixForm`

Comment: The documentation clearly reads: "`Total[list,Infinity]` totals all elements at any level in `list`. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as suggested:

```
b = {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}};
```

Then use

```
Total[b,Infinity]
```

to sum over every entire, or do it more explicitly as

```
Sum[b[[n,1]],{n,1,10}]
```

Comment: Thank you Fabian!. The last command is what I need exactly..